# RestSharp can't properly auto-deserialize my JSON response - but JSON.NET can - why?

Tags: json, json.net, restsharp

I have an odd issue with JSON here. I'm calling a REST web service from my C# code using RestSharp (v104.4), and the call works fine.

The issue is with the JSON that gets returned - if I let RestSharp "automatically" decode it - it doesn't work. If I deserialize the JSON I get back manually, using JSON.NET, it works just fine. Why?

My RestSharp request:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(MyUrl, Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

IRestResponse<JsonResponse> response = _restClient.Execute<JsonResponse>(request);
```

This is the raw JSON I get back from this call:

```
{ "roomURL":"https://dev.mycompany.com/room/abc123", "text":"Click here. ....." }
```

Using this class, I am trying to have RestSharp automatically deserialize this response:

```
public class JsonResponse {
    public string RoomUrl { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

But using RestSharp - the `response.Data` I get back has a `null` value for `RoomUrl`.

However, if I use JSON.NET to manually deserialize the response into a `JsonResult`, both pieces of information (`RoomUrl` and `Text`) are properly recognized - no issues at all.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(response.Content);
```

Here, `result.RoomUrl` gets the returned URL without any hitch.

I'm just a bit baffled why RestSharp doesn't properly deserialize the JSON returned into a `JsonResponse` object - any ideas?

I also tried putting a `[JsonProperty("roomURL")]` on the `RoomUrl` string in the `JsonResponse` - but that doesn't make any difference, it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem has been solved after posting to the RestSharp Google Group.

RestSharp as of v103 doesn't use JSON.NET anymore, but its own JSON deserializer - which handles certain things slightly differently.

The name `roomURL` in the JSON response I got wasn't being automatically "picked up" by the RestSharp JSON deserializer - but using a `DeserializeAs` attribute on my response class solved the issue:

```
public class JsonResponse {
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "roomURL")]
    public string RoomUrl { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Now the JSON response from my request gets automatically deserialized as expected, and I can go about using it.

Thanks to Andrew Young in the RestSharp Google Group for solving this!

Comment: so the restsharp deserializer expects properties to start with lower case?

Comment: restsharp deserializer will not pick up the mapping between `RoomUrl` and `roomURL` because it doesn't follow these mapping rules in the wiki: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization